# Override paragraph size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 2 paragraphs in a div, and I need one of them to be 14px, and the other one 16px. I've tried to put the first one into a class but it doesn't take the 14px value...
As a resume, I need "12 mei, 2014 | Sport" to have font-size 14px, and the other one 16px.

Here's my code:

```css
#kolom4 {
    width: 1440px;
    height: 718px;
    background: #222222;
}
#kolom4 h2 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-top: 29px;
}
#kolom4 p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#kolom4 h3 {
    color: #fdd400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.kolom4Date {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
}
#section1 {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 249px;
    margin-bottom: 62px;
}
#text_img1 {
    float: right;
    width: 383px;
    height: 220px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#text_img1 a {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fdd400;
    font-style: oblique;
}
```

```html
<div id="kolom4">
            <h2>Nieuws</h2>
            <div id="section1">
                <img src="images/kolom4Image1.jpg" />
                <div id="text_img1">
                    <h3>Lorum ipsum</h3>
                    <p class="kolom4Date">12 mei, 2014 | Sport</p><br>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam [...]</p><br>
                    <a href="#">Lees meer ></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end kolom4 -->
```

Comment: I want to question why you have an id called "kolumn4" which is obviously iteration for of an id called "kolumn" which means the item isnt realy a uniqe item which does mean you may should use an classes instead of id's.. there

Comment: In my project I also have kolumn1,kolum2,....,kolum7, and that's why I used this notation...is it wrong?

Comment: Depends what "kolumn" is. If all the elements are basically the same and you just need a mark counting mark i'd use the class "kolumn" for basic styles and an additional class "kolumn1" or "kolumn2" for the specific styling.

Ids are for UNIQUE elements that means only 1 per page.

Comment: Each "kolom" is a different section for my layout...so I assume that it is correctly to use an id, because each of them have different properties.

Comment: Yes, using an id there is correct then but this makes the naming of the ids kinda questionable cause i would assume 2 things called "thing1" and "thing2" to be similar if not equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
.kolom4Date {
```

to:

```
#kolom4 .kolom4Date {
```

Now the problem is you use ID's for styling, which are way too specific and you'll run into other problems in the long run. try using classes instead and it will become much easier.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm..it is a problem that I have used in the whole project id's?

Comment: Well, you just make it more difficult on yourself, since ID's "weigh" more than other selectors, so you'll probably find that in the end you get long selectors like `#some-id .some-class #another-id p {}`. Classes are easier to manage, but just continue, it's always good to learn!

Comment: Ah, for a moment I thought that I have to change all my id's into classes :D ... next time I will use your advice, tanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, web development is all about learning new things and using it in your current or next project! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the style font-size: 16px because of the way you're targeting the elements. Instead of using

```
#kolom4 p{}
```

use:

```
.kolom4p{ font-size: 16; }
```

then add the class kolom4p to the paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.kolom4Date {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Please DO NOT do this.
!important is very evil.

Theres very few cases where u need to do this.
I discourage the use of !important at any given time!!

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I also found that #text_img1 .kolom3Date {font-size:14px;} also works

Comment: Never use !important. It becomes a real mess when you have to override things later. Simply use the CSS cascade to adjust styling. Prevent using ID's altogether, use classes, it's more flexible.